# Ninject Custom AuthorizeAttribute Injection isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filter, ninject, authorize-attribute

I've hit a bit of a wall and was hoping someone could point out where I'm going wrong.

I've been using Ninject to Inject into custom ActionFilterAttributes and this is working fine:

```
kernel.BindFilter<CriticalErrorAttribute>(FilterScope.Last, 1);
```

I'm now trying to inject into a custom AuthorizeAttribute. I've got the syntax correct so that I'm inserting the Role and custom attributes:

```
kernel.BindFilter<Authorisation>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
.WhenActionMethodHas<Authorisation>()
.WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorisation>("Roles", n => n.Roles)
.WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorisation>("Years", n => n.Years);
```

The attribute is being executed correctly and the roles and years are being inserted fine, my issue is that a service I'm trying to inject in is always null:

```
[Inject]
public IUserServices userService { get; set; }
```

In normal ActionFilterAttributes the service is injected fine, but here it isn't.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deriving from an attribute you should implement the corresponding interface e.g. `IAuthorizationFilter` or `IActionFilter` and use a different normal attribut to mark the controllers or actions for which you want to apply that filter

```
public class AuthorisationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter ....
public class Authorization : Attribute ....

kernel.BindFilter<AuthorisationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
      .WhenActionMethodHas<Authorisation>()
      .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorisation>("Roles", n => n.Roles)
      .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorisation>("Years", n => n.Years);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have very issue similar to the already asked question, but I can't solve it. 
I am adding my custom authorization filters, which inside have access to the db context. The dbcontext is defined to be used InRequestScope (Ninject Binding). When I hit the point where the filter is executing I am getting an error that dbcontext is already been disposed.

```
 void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
....
var customerPermissions = _authorizationService.GetCustomersListForPermission(_userProvider.CurrentUser.Username,
                this.PermissionEnums);
..
}
```

The aurhorization service asks the db for permissions for the current user - this means that Ninject should create a new dbcontext instance, but this dosn't happen...
I read that "The MVC framework itsself caches filters. " https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Filters-and-Scoped

But can't get how to implement my filter bindings.

Currently these are the bindings that I have:

```
kernel.Bind<TDBContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
     kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();//.InThreadScope();

            kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkManager>().To<UnitOfWorkManager>().InRequestScope();

  #region UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter
            kernel.BindFilter<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
              .WhenActionMethodHas<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>()
              .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>("permissionEnums", att => att.PermissionEnums);

            kernel.BindFilter<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
               .WhenActionMethodHas<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>()
               .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter>("permissionEnums", att => att.PermissionEnums);
            #endregion




   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        #region Private Fields
        private static readonly ObjectCache _permissionCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UserAllCSPermissionBasedAuthFilter));

        [Inject]
        public  IAuthorizationService _authorizationService { get; set; }/// DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthorizationService>();
```